# Library is installed, but does not allow configuring adonis

Tags: adonis.js

I'm trying to run node ace configure @adonisjs/lucid, but I only get this error
Error: Package subpath './package.json' is not defined by "exports" in /node_modules/@adonisjs/lucid/package.json.
Node Version: v21.6.1
Yarn version: 1.22.21
Npm version: 10.2.4
node ace configure @adonisjs/lucid